# What does 0x0(r15) mean?

Tags: assembly

I'm pretty avanced with assembler, but I don't know this, an I really can't find anything about this:

```
cmp   #0x2f44, 0x0(r15)
```

what does `0x0(r15)` mean?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, Sydney mission from microcorruption? looking into the same thing :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a relative addressing which means that offset `0x0` from value in `r15` register.

Suppose you have a instruction `movq 8(%r15), %rax` which means that move the value stored at address contained in `r15` + offset `8` into register `rax`.

A negative no will show negative offset.